# Which UTF8 - phpMyAdmin display Chinese, Russian, Arabic correctly?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, phpmyadmin, collation

I need to input content in 10 languages  in MYSQL database (problem ones are: Chinese, Russian, Arabic) and client should be able to read and edit them through phpMyAdmin as well as admin area.

I have used utf8-bin, utf8_unicode_ci, utf8_general_ci, but the characters does not show properly in phpMyAdmin. In addition I need to consider the search and sort problems and as I can't understand the above languages I am worrying that some characters might be escaped or mapped incorrectly.

Which UT8 is the best in this case?

Is it normal for phpMyAdmin to display characters as 'å‹•åŠ›å“ç‰Œçµåˆå“ç‰Œèˆ‡ç§‘æŠ€'?

How can I make phpMyAdmin  display the content in human readable way?

Comment: did you solve this problem? I had a similar problem as I can not display arabic correctly although I checked all php,html,javascript and database files and all are UTF-8 ?!

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your database it seems (unless the database's contents is also UTF-8 mojibake, being double-mojibaked on the way to your browser); the output example you have included looks like that your browser's encoding to interpret the phpMyAdmin page in is incorrect, most likely some ISO-8859 variant. Check and make sure that your browser's encoding is UTF-8.

The different collations specify different rules for sorting and searching, but the encoding is still the same. If you are storing multiple languages in the database, use `utf8_general_ci`.

Comment: Thank you, I have checked phpMyAdmin in IE, Firefox, Chrome; page encoding is set to UTF-8.

Comment: Then it appears that your data is being interpreted as an ISO-8859 variant encoding, then afterwards, converted to UTF-8, on the way into the database.

Comment: yes that is exactly the case, I just inserted directly to phpMyAdmin it looks OK? Any idea how in PHP/ SQL query I can enforce UTF8 encoding.

Comment: Well, there isn't a single solution to this problem. You need to follow the data as it goes in, through the HTML form, through the PHP, and through to the SQL query, to see exactly where the data is being misinterpreted.

Comment: As far as i know all php files are using utf8, HTML headers are UTF8 aswell. Browser at the time of input is forced to UTF8.

Comment: based on your advise i found the solution as follow : PHP function that forces the Mysqli to utf8, Now everything works fine  mysqli_set_charset ( $mysqli,'utf8'); or $mysqli->set_charset("utf8")